# read_page_mailboxes permission with Messenger ChatBot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm building a Messenger ChatBot which can handle automated answers and can switch to human conversation with Messenger Handover Protocol. My app is in development and I requested *publish_pages, read_page_mailboxes and manage_pages* to do that (I got an extended Page token) and It worked perfectly!

Now, I'm facing an issue. I Want to be in production and request permission for *publish_pages, read_page_mailboxes and manage_pages* and Facebook is asking for the platform (like in the picture below): I know I have to complete the other fields... but

[image]

It's not a web app, neither and android app... or something else! It's a Messenger ChatBot.

How can I do to request permission properly? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you send page admins to log in to your app to begin with then?

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry I don't understand what you said.

Comment: Are you only going to use this app yourself? Then you don’t need to submit it for review. Or do you want other people to use your bot on their pages as well? Then you need to implement Facebook login, so that they can grant the necessary permissions to your app. And if you implement login, you’ll have to do it on one of those platforms ...

Comment: Oh great, so you said that if I want to use read_page_mailboxes in my personal Facebook Page with my personal Messenger ChatBot, I don't need to ask Facebook permission and I can stay like that with my extended token. Is that correct ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Answer (score 0):

You need to have special permission from facebook to use those permission in your app. Click 'Add Details' beside each of the permission and fill up the form properly with required use case scenarios. Then submit the app to facebook for app review. After couple of days your app and bot should be verified if everything is ok.